# ZSTD - I forgot to tar the directory first

Tags: data-recovery

It is as the title says. I was backing up my home directory to my server whilst I re-image my pc, and I forgot to tar it before compressing it with zstdmt. When decompressed, it just spits out a file. I tried unpacking it as a tar, but no luck. I don't have a backup of some of this data, so I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks. (:

Comment: Well, what was the command used to create the archive (before passing it to `zstdmt`) ?

Comment: It wasn't in an archive, and that's the problem. it didn't give an error when I passed it the whole directory (/home/username). The file zstdmt gave me was a similar size to the original directory. (70G vs 84G).

Comment: it still doesn't describe the exact command used

Comment: iirc, it was something like `zstdmt /home/username -8 -o /mnt/server/home_backup.zst`

Comment: That's weird, because a command like `zstdmt DIR` is supposed to fail immediately : `zstd: DIR is a directory -- ignored`

Comment: after a little playing around, it looks like I used the -r flag. this doesn't help me much though.

Comment: Ah, I see.
`zstd -r DIR` will recursively compress all files within `DIR`. Normally, it produces one `*.zst` compressed file per original file.
However, it's possible to push the result into `stdout` instead, by adding `-c`. `stdout` can then be sent into a file with `-c > FILE`.
The command `-o FILE` achieves just the same thing.

The problem with this construction is that compressed content is pushed into `stdout`, but no metadata survives. Which means, original names of files and arborescence disappear.
I'm afraid it can't be solved easily.